# Problem with author-date bibliography

Tags: natbib, apa-style

For submitting my manuscript to the journal “[Communications in Algebra](http://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?journalCode=lagb20&page=instructions)”, I want cite references in the text by author and date only enclosed in parentheses, and At the end of the article, list the references in alphabetical order. Examples:

Journal: Hvala, B. Generalized derivations in rings. *Comm. Algebra* 26:1147–1166.

Book: Birkenmeier, G. F., Heatherly, H. E., Lee, E. K. (1995). Completely prime ideals and radicals in Near-rings. In: Fong, Y., et al., ed. *Proceedings of Near-rings and Near-Fields*. Kluwer, pp. 63–73.

I use `natbib` with `apalike` style, but I can't do it. Is there any solution?

Comment: What do you want to look like that? The entry in the bibliography or the citation? If the former, what do you want the citation to look like? Please edit your question adding that.

Comment: Using the `natbib` package and its command `\citep` should be no problem. Judging from the journal's website, they don't provide a custom bibliography style file (with extension `.bst`) for authors. However, you should be able to use the `makebst` utility -- at a command prompt, type "latex makebst" and follow the detailed prompts -- to create a style file that implements the journal's stylistic guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work in a straightforward way using the `\citep` command from `natbib`. Note that the references do not look exactly as in your example. If that is the problem, you need a different bibliography style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Dadsetani.bib}
@article{Hvala,
  author = {Hvala, B.},
  title = {Generalized derivations in rings},
  journal = {Comm. Algebra},
  volume = 26,
  pages = {1147--1166},
  year = 1998,
}

@inproceedings{Birkenmeier,
  author = {Birkenmeier, G. F. and Heatherly, H. E. and Lee, E. K.},
  title = {Completely prime ideals and radicals in Near-rings},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of Near-rings and Near-Fields},
  publisher = {Kluwer},
  year = 1995,
  pages = {63--73},
  editor = {Fong, Y. and others},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citep{Hvala}, \citep{Birkenmeier}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Dadsetani}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]